# comments are not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, comments

I have commented on a stylesheet as this

```
.cols-3 .column-1
{
        /*float:left;*/
        width:29%;
        /*padding:0px 5px;
        padding-top:50px;*/
}
```

and it is working in firefox but not in chrome. Chrome still showing commented styles.

Comment: Please don't link to your site but to a minimal example reproducing your problem (for example on http://jsbin.com)

Comment: Did you make sure that wasn't a cache problem ?

Comment: And how did you find that css is having comments shown??

Comment: clear your browser cache.

Comment: Press CTRL+F5 to do a clean refresh

Comment: In google chrome they are displaying as before comments but after comments in firefox is display properly as I wanted.

Comment: I have done a clean refresh with CTRL+F5 but doesn't display as firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cache problem. Try this:

> Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar.
>   Select Tools.
>   Select Clear browsing data.
>   In the dialog that appears, select the checkboxes for the types of information that you want to remove.
>   Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete. Select beginning of time to delete everything.
>   Click Clear browsing data.

Source: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en